# Elasticsearch runtime fields as clickable URL

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to add a runtime field in my index which will be in fact an external URL.
I'm trying to make it directly clickable in discover.

I've created the runtime field with :

```
PUT apm-7.16.2-span-000003/_mapping
 {
   "runtime": {
     "runtimeExternalLink": {
       "type": "keyword",
       "script": {
         "source": "emit('http://echo.jsontest.com/trace.id/' + doc['trace.id'].value + '/service.name/' + doc['service.name'].value)"
       }
     } 
   } 
 }
```

The field successfully appears as a text (showing the link) but not clickable.
In discover I've tried to define a format for the field.

[image: Format Configuration]

But the resulting link is URL encoded and therefore totally broken :

[image: Broken URL]

Can anyone have an idea to make it clickable ?

PS : I've managed to do it using a [deprecated] scripted fields but I'm trying to do it with the new way.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and I feel your pain, spent hours of trying to solve it.

Solution: just leave "URL template" blank, no need for {{value}}

Comment: same here... hours wasted until I see this.  Much thanks.